# Custom Post Type 'single-custom.php' next and previous links stuck in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a custom post type in Wordpress called 'cases'. For the single page I've created a single-case.php, which all works fined but one thing:

Right outside the While loop I'm trying to have a 'Next' and 'Previous' link, like so:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'next item &gt;') ?>
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '&lt; previous item') ?>
```

But they get stuck in a loop. Once it reaches a certain article Wordpress gets stuck and loops the same two articles over and over.

Here's the full (stripped down) template:

```
... Header ...
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="span4">
        <?php if(count($aImages)) : ?>
            <?php foreach($aImages as $aImage) : ?>
                ....
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="span7">
            <div class="case-title"><?php the_title();?></div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
... Footer ...

<div class="next-posts pull-right"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'volgend item &gt;') ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts pull-left"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '&lt; vorig item') ?></div>
```

**UPDATE**

For some reason this fixes my issue:

```
<div class="prev-posts pull-left">
    <?php
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
    if($prev_post) {
       $prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
       echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title. '" class=" "><strong><<< &quot;'. $prev_title . '&quot;</strong></a>' . "\n";
                    }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="next-posts pull-right">
    <?
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if($next_post) {
       $next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));
       echo "\t" . '<a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_title. '" class=" "><strong>&quot;'. $next_title . '&quot; >>></strong></a>' . "\n";
                    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: As much as I trust WP isn't selecting the same posts many times from the database, can you show how you are selecting them anyway just to rule that out?

Comment: I'm not defining any custom WP Queries. I'm using the WP template Hierarchy logic, so WP should deal with the proper query. So unless WP is broken/buggy, there's something I'm forgetting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<div class="prev-posts pull-left">
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if($prev_post) {
   $prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title. '" class=" "><strong><<< &quot;'. $prev_title . '&quot;</strong></a>' . "\n";
                }
?>
</div>

<div class="next-posts pull-right">
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
if($next_post) {
   $next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_title. '" class=" "><strong>&quot;'. $next_title . '&quot; >>></strong></a>' . "\n";
                }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

next_post_link is meant to be called from within the loop.[enter link description here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link).  Since this is for a single post, you can safely move the next_post_link and previous_post_link lines into the loop.

**UPDATE:**

Not sure why you're getting that behavior, but you can add something like this in:

```
<?php if ( (get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) ) { ?>
    <div class="next-posts pull-right"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'volgend item &gt;') ?></div>
<?php } elseif ( (get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)) ){ ?>
    <div class="prev-posts pull-left"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '&lt; vorig item') ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your absolutely right, but it doesn't change to problem :)

Comment: But that is the problem!  When you use something meant for the loop outside of the loop, you'll get strange results.

Comment: I placed the links inside the loop, makes no difference, still stuck in the loop.

Comment: Ok, next post link initially loops through all of the single pages, but once it has looped through all of them, it doesn't disappear, it get's stuck in a loop of 4 (skipping the first item). The previous post link does not work on any of the single pages...